# Google chart: Add style to axis's title individually

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I have a gantt chart which is created from a stacked bar chart. I am trying to make the h-axis titles look different from each others, like in the image below. I've look into the API and could not find any solution.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: You cannot style axis labels individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual styling is not supported with Google API. So if you can handle risk of future code break you can 'manually' change text properties.

As a example I used [Simple Example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#SimpleExample) from google docs and change it to the stacked bar chart.

The following elements are created in DOM for labels on the left (2004 - 2007):

```
<g>
    <text text-anchor="end" x="147" y="139.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2004</text>
</g>
<g>
    <text text-anchor="end" x="147" y="216.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2005</text>
</g>
<g>
    <text text-anchor="end" x="147" y="293.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2006</text>
</g>
<g>
    <text text-anchor="end" x="147" y="370.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2007</text>
</g>
```

You can change them using for example:

```
    var labels = document.querySelectorAll('text[text-anchor=end]');

    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        if (labels[i].textContent == '2004') {
            labels[i].setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');
            labels[i].setAttribute('font-size', '20');
        }
        if (labels[i].textContent == '2005') {
            labels[i].setAttribute('font-style', 'italic');
            labels[i].setAttribute('font-size', '20');
        }
    }
```

See whole [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bavuw/1/edit).

Comment: Thank you. This enabled me to change the cursor to a pointer when hovering on the axis titles.